# Postfix Outgoing Email Authentication

Tags: server, security, postfix, mail, smtp

I have a VPS that I'm using as a webserver and an email server. I have an issue with postfix. It's not asking for a password on outgoing email from an unauthorized domain.

This is a telnet call from a non-existent domain to my local email:

```
telnet smtp.mydomain.com 25
Trying XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX...
Connected to smtp.mydomain.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.mydomain.com ESMTP Postfix
EHLO smtp.mydomain.com
250-smtp.mydomain.com
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250 8BITMIME
mail from:<hello@hello.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to:<myaddress@mydomain.com>
250 2.1.5 Ok
data
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Subject: test

Hello

.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 94DC2150BCA
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
```

On the other hand, if I send an email from an existing internal address to another existing internal address through telnet, postfix stops sending because it needs authentication.

```
telnet smtp.mydomain.com 25
Trying XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX...
Connected to smtp.mydomain.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.mydomain.com ESMTP Postfix
EHLO smtp.mydomain.com
250-smtp.mydomain.com
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250 8BITMIME
mail from:<myaddress@mydomain.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to:<myotheraddress@mydomain.com>
453 4.7.1 <myaddress@mydomain.com>: Sender address rejected: not logged in
quit
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Here is my postfix config file:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin xxgdb $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
delay_warning_time = 4
disable_vrfy_command = no
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 52428800
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
mydomain = smtp.mydomain.com
myhostname = smtp.mydomain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = /etc/mailname
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.2.2/README_FILES
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/zpanel/configs/postfix/mysql-relay_domains_maps.cf
relayhost =
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.2.2/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_client_restrictions =
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination,reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_login_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/zpanel/configs/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender_login_maps
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_sender_login_mismatch, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unlisted_sender, reject_unauthenticated_sender_login_mismatch, permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unverified_sender
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/smtp.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/smtp.mydomain.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
soft_bounce = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/zpanel/configs/postfix/mysql-virtual_alias_maps.cf, regexp:/etc/zpanel/configs/postfix/virtual_regexp, hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/zpanel/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/zpanel/configs/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/zpanel/configs/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 150
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

I'd like postfix to ALWAYS ask for passwords when someone sends an email through telnet.

Where am I going wrong? This issue has become really frustrating lately.

Answer (score 0):

telnet on port 25 simulates the behaviour of actual mail servers sending messages, so typically a mail server will accept emails to addresses at domains configured to be 'local' on the mail server, and that sort of explains the first scenario you describe...

... on that basis you'd expect the server to just accept emails to local domains as in your 2nd scenario, but it requests authentication. That'll be down to your particular configuration...

I recommend working through Postfix's [address verification](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_VERIFICATION_README.html) documentation, which should help make sense of what's going on (possibly also [SASL](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html) documentation). Also consider configuration both in `main.cf` and `master.cf`: Using these correctly allows you to have differing configuration for different ports. Modern best practise for mail servers is to have port 25 dedicated to receiving emails, and port 587 dedicated to 'submitting' (sending) emails. Having different configurations for these ports means you can more easily focus your configuration for port 25 to 'MX' email (mail for local domains), and port 587 to mail submission (also pay attention to encryption with TLS).

As to particular settings, this will vary according to your particular requirements. It's worth noting that the various `_restrictions` settings are lists that are tested in sequence, so in your current settings in `main.cf` you have (reformatted for readability),

```
smtpd_client_restrictions =
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_unauth_destination,
    reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_relay_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
    reject_sender_login_mismatch,
    reject_unknown_sender_domain,
    reject_unlisted_sender,
    reject_unauthenticated_sender_login_mismatch,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_unverified_sender
```

I suggest reviewing these, and the order of the options carefully; I would also recommend a final explicit `permit` or `reject` in each list so it's very clear what happens if none of the prior tests match.

Then also take a look at `master.cf` where these options can be overridden, for example for mail submission you might have particular `_restrictions`,

```
submission inet n       -       -       -       - smtpd
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

Compare this to your statement "I'd like postfix to ALWAYS ask for passwords when someone sends an email through telnet" - the above example `master.cf` line would require authentication for mail submission.